# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /computesalary.jsp at line 22

Tags: java

My problem is this (picture below) I've been searching about it and the answers were NullPointerException, but I believe this is not a NullPointer, if it is please tell me what parameter returns `null`. I can provide more pictures if necessary thanks!

[image: ErrorPage]

Comment: "The ATM number you provided is incorrect" seems pretty straightforward. Also, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: oh sorry but that message was defined by me what i am trying to do is if its not a valid card then it would throw the exception that i made (rather my teacher made) this is the class: public InvalidATMCardException() { super("The ATM number you provided is incorrect. Please enter a valid ATM number."); }

Answer (score 0):

As you see the root cause, it clearly stating that "The ATM number you provided is incorrect. Please enter valid ATM number". Try to check the ATM number you entered was correct.

Comment: oh sorry but that message was defined by me
what i am trying to do is if its not a valid card then it would throw the exception that i made (rather my teacher made)
this is the class:
public InvalidATMCardException() {
  super("The ATM number you provided is incorrect. Please enter a"
    + " valid ATM number.");
 }